# The passive voice of: “Do I watch TV everyday?”

Tags: passive-voice

I am just preparing a table of English grammar tenses and I am stuck in passive voice of following sentence. Sentence in question is example of Simple Present Tense,

> Do I watch TV everyday?

I am just wondering, will it be,

> Is TV watched by me everyday?

OR

> Does TV watched by me everyday?

If both are the correct sentences in daily talking then which one is right?

Answer (score 3):

`Is TV watched by me everyday?` is correct.  `Does TV watched by me everyday?` is not.  If you're looking for a version that starts with "does", you could say `Does TV get watched by me everyday?`.  None of these sentences is particularly natural sounding though.  I guess watching TV isn't a good fit for the passive voice, which is ironic since watching TV is such a passive activity.